# GIT, изменения в существующем файле

Tags: git

Вопрос в следующем, нужно создать новую ветку “feature”. Добавить любую строку в файл с песней и сделать комит в новую ветку, до этого у меня был создан файл в ветке main, он назвался song.txt, ветку feauters я создал, но не могу понять, как можно теперь зайти именно в файл song.txt и внести изменения туда, то есть добавить строчку любую, подскажите

Comment: Причем это изменение надо сделать командой, можно было просто зайти в файл и добавить там строчку любую, а потом уже git add, git commit и git push

Comment: Не можешь понять как открыть файл???? Открывай и изменяй любым привычным способом

Comment: `echo "asdfsdfsdf" >> ./song.txt`

Comment: Таким образом внесутся изменения в существующий файл?